# Issue with UIScrollView and UIKeyboard

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

i'm having some issues over here. I've got a UITextView that get's dismiss by the keyboard when I tap inside, so, what i'm trying to do here is a UIScrollView that allow me to see what I'm writing in the TextView...

This is my code so far:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow {
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide {
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}

-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
        if (movedUp)
        {
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeZero;
            scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 308);
//            rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
//            rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        }
        else
        {
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeZero;
            scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 190, 320, 308);
//            rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
//            rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        }
        self.view.frame = rect;
    }];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
```

The problem is that the code isn't working properly, when I tap the textView the View instead of going up, it goes down...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `UITextView` is **already** a scroll view. It should scroll automatically when you enter more text than is visible. Also, the user can scroll the text inside by himself any time.

Comment: No, you didn't understand the question, my problem that the Keyboard dismiss the UITextView when is called... And I wan't to scroll the whole UIView for that the keyboard don't dismiss my textView...

Comment: Do you mean the keyboard **is covering** your text view? For a keyboard cannot dismiss a text view, only the other way round :P.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to all my problems!

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    [self scrollViewAsd:130];

}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    [self scrollViewAsd:0];

}

- (void)scrollViewAsd:(float) inset
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, inset, 0);
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, inset); 

    }];
}
```